# Taylor formula of $\partial_x^{\alpha}P(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials

Let $P$ be a polynomial with variable $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and degree  $r$

I want to write the Taylor formula of

$\partial_x^{\alpha}P(x)-\partial_x^{\alpha}P(0)$

for all $\alpha\in\left\{1,2\right\}$

Thanks for your help.